# Module Directive vs. Module Service Injection

Tags: angularjs

I'm looking to sure up my understanding of dependency injection and make sure my understanding is correct. I'm following a course at the moment that takes 2 modules as examples, ngMessage vs. ngResource. Within my app module injection I include ['ngResource', 'ngMessage'].

Within the controller I inject the service $resource (for ngResource).

Then in my view html I can make use of the ngMessages directive $error.

My question is why doesn't ngMessage require any insertion in to the controller? Is it the difference between a service ($resource) vs directive ($error)?

I just want to make sure I'm clear on why ngMessage didn't require any form of injection in to the controller. If my thinking is right, all modules that are injected in to your app will have all directives immediately available in the view, but any services will need to be injected in to the controller.

app.js

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngResource']);

myApp.controller('mainController', function('$resource') {
    console.log($resource)
}); 
<form name="myForm">
    <input type = "text" ng-model="field" name="myField" required minlength="5"/>
    <div ng-messages="myForm.myField.$error">
        <div ng-message="required">You did not enter a field</div>
        <div ng-message ="minlength">The value entered is too short</div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Why are you learning AngularJs? You should be learning Angular.

Comment: Unless you have taken a job supporting a legacy application that uses AngularJs your time would be much better spent learning a more recent framework like Angular or Vue.

Comment: I just want to for understanding @AdrianBrand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directive are available at the module level and can be used in any template in the module or module that import the module that declares it.

Services are injected as objects into your controllers for accessing data from them and sharing data between controllers.